# Why is the term "bug" very negative to some?

Tags: teamwork, issue-tracking

Our software user interface was originally written in another language. Some of the English translations are poor. When I raised one of these as a bug, the manager got angry with something like "this is not a bug, but a possible improvement".

We might argue over severity, priority, re-categorise it, address it immediately or in a future version, or even ignore it altogether. Whatever. If you cannot fix it immediately (because it affects documentation for example), just write it down and move on.

To me "bug" is just a general catch-all for "error", "undesired behaviour", "fault", "defect", etc. It is entirely neutral, even positive. Its been helpful over the years to describe issues, without getting into complicated, sometimes heated, conversations about what exactly is meant by a specific term.

Most colleagues are unaffected by this storm-in-a-teacup, but over the years a number of engineer and manager colleagues will wholeheartedly agree that X is an "issue", but get insistent (often angry) if X is referred to as a "bug". The offense seems to be specifically with the word "bug". Why? Its just a word. Most software has many, mostly minor, bugs. Is there some special meaning to "bug"?

What is the best general practice to:

- be more diplomatic and defuse tension over terms?
- improve the chances an issue, however described, will actually be fixed sometime in the future?

Comment: Because some software engineers and managers view bugs as "something the developer missed."  It's a variation on the "Stay Positive" trope.  See [The Polyanna](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThePollyanna).

Comment: Fair enough, but to err is human. We all make mistakes. Why get hot under the collar?

Comment: If they don’t like the word “bug”, what about “creepy crawlies”?

Comment: "Bug" implies that somebody made a mistake in the implementation. In some cases it could make a big difference, e.g. a contractor might be contractually obliged to fix bugs under the originally agreed price but change requests would be paid for separately. So financially it could make big difference. But for in-house agile development it might not matter at all how an issue is classified.

Comment: As already said, the word **bug** suggests that an error was made by the programmer and the program does not do what it is supposed to do. It is important to distinguish this from other issues, such as feature requests, or requests to change existing functionality, because this can have consequences for who pays for it. An error might need to be fixed under warranty (the company who is developing the software pays) while a new feature or change is something the client would typically pay for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This question is surely opinion-based, but I've noticed this reaction as well. This question might be more appropriate for [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), but even then it might not be the best fit.*

---

The term "bug" is not offensive. As others have pointed out, a bug is an unintended behavior that deviates from the intended behavior. Bugs happen. As for *why* people gets so upset about reporting bugs?

Politics.

A bug is a mistake. Mistakes are negative. Negative actions have professional consequences, such as missing a promotion, raise or just being chewed out by upper management. To "file a bug" is tantamount to accusing some people of being careless — perhaps an entire team of people. Basically some people view it as an insult or an accusation. That's all.

Comment: "To "file a bug" is tantamount to accusing some people of being careless — perhaps an entire team of people. Basically some people view it as an insult or an accusation." OH boy, I can only imagine that kind of software that emerges from an office with this kind of loaded meaning behind "filing a bug"

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: People do not stick around very long, I can tell you that from personal experience. See also [Fear Driven Development](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FearDrivenDevelopmentFDD.aspx). This plays an important role in people viewing "bugs" as an insult or accusation. It indicates larger organizational problems that cannot be solved with code.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: Yeah, that's how I feel. If you take offense (get angry, whatever) to someone calling bad translations a "bug" when they think it should have been called an "Improvement"...then you've got bigger issues. Am new at this job and I can see that people are reticent to raise issues against the software which is pretty "buggy" (at risk of using this term imprecisely, of course!). I see a connection.

Comment: @AlainD TBF, I wouldn't call that a bug, because I associate that explicitly with code misbehavior. There's all kinds of issues that can happen "behind the scenes" (dependencies aren't updated, tests are ignored, code is messy, variable names are misspelt, etc.), but I wouldn't classify any of those as bugs. Though I don't have a better catch-all term to suggest for them, either.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: I'm an experienced software developer (though from a Chemistry/Physics background) and have used "bug" as my catch-all for years. It feels right and works for me, but this sort of discussion helps me understand how and where mine and others understanding are sometimes messed up! This is subtle stuff and I need to tread with greater care in future...though I don't think I'll ever understand why someone would get pissed off over what is often a fuzzy distinction.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Great link that FDD article. The mention of legacy code and fear about changing it describes our situation! Perhaps add that link to your answer.

Comment: I was in a large project once where the term 'defect' was being used for both bugs and missed/unspecified requirements.  There were a lot of missed requirements and they vastly outnumbered the actual bugs.  What's the problem?  Management was being told that the delays and poor results were due to the large number of 'defects'.  Not knowing that this meant 'missing requirements' management (rightfully) understood this to mean there was a problem with the developers and nothing was done to address the requirements issue.  Misclassification and miscommunication have real consequences.

Comment: '"To "file a bug" is tantamount to accusing some people of being careless' - well, if people feel they are being personally attacked when someone files "a bug", than that indicates there are serious problems with company culture, and possibly with how management approaches things.

Answer (score 3):

It is extremely helpful to categorize software issues (bugs, errors, ...) based on which expectations aren't met and on which documents these expectations are based. If the software does not behave as specified you could clearly label that as a bug. If it doesn't behave as documented you'd need to check whether the documentation promises something that wasn't specified, in which case there's an error in the documentation. The most difficult cases are implicit assumptions, as some are clearly justified even if not explicitly specified or documented (the software should not crash when I enter bogus search words,) while others only seem obvious to the user but were never part of the specification (search results should be sorted by popularity, or navigation results should show this and not that route because that route is currently affected by roadworks.)

Once there is a common understanding what categories there are and how they're properly handled, it's much easier to find names for each that work for all affected parties.

Answer (score 2):

> To me, anything that any user has a problem with is a "bug".

Well, then you are using the word incorrectly. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug):

> A software bug is an error, flaw or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or unexpected result, or to behave in unintended ways.

A bug is the mistake a developer made either in designing the system or in implementing it.

If I was hired to build a system to a specification and the specification says "Users cannot delete their content" and you file a bug that says "But users want that, that's a problem", then I'd think you do not really know what the word "bug" means.

Next time, before you file a bug, look up what the specified behavior actually is. If you can find a specification that says you are correct, it was planned to behave differently, *then* file a bug. Otherwise use a different term. Improvement? New Feature? Issue? Depends on your organization.

Comment: The LibreOffice definition of a bug is sensible: "...something that makes the software behave in a way that a reasonable user would not want it to behave..." (https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport). This roughly the same as the Wiki definition. A mistranslation is likely to be an `unexpected result` as far as the user is concerned. Defining a bug as a "...mistake a developer made..." is too limited.

Answer (score 2):

I like to think that software developers should be understanding about bugs.  Its their job.  The one time it could get touchy is if a developer was forced to put their name on a piece of code that was poorly specified and they feel the feature was ambiguous from the start.

From a managment perspective, there is politics to consider, as Greg mentions.  Often the business world is built around arbitrarily drawn lines in the sand.  An improvement to the software runs through a different path than an error.  For example, an error might involve notifying all of the users of your software that the bug exists.  That can be expensive, both in terms of actual cost and "good will."

This is, of course, a slippery slope -- a dangerous game.  A manager who abuses this approach to hide bugs can cause grief for the company later on.  However, if a skilled manager knows his or her clients well, he may understand that this particular problem can be solved unofficially for far less cost than marking it as a bug to be solved officially.  Or perhaps the business has multiple pools of money, where bug fixes must come out of one but features come out of another.  The difference between a bug fix and a feature request may be whether they can make the fix this quarter or next quarter depending on which way you round the ambiguity.  This is a business decision, and an ethics decision.  For example, if the problem has not caused any problems for the customers yet and you know the customers always move to the latest version when you release it, and you know the customer cares about getting this fixed fast, it may be better to resolve the ambiguity towards a feature request.

While a developer should absolutely care about how the business works and have input into how things proceed, there is definitely a reason the manager exists in the first place.  If you are interested, try to approach the manager and find out why they push these decisions.  If you feel ethically bound to call it a bug, you may learn the correct language to use to convince the manager to agree it is a bug as well.

Some things will always be bugs.  For example, if there's a buffer overrun, the only way that could possibly be a feature request is if the customer had previously not cared about security and is now in the process of shifting their stance to care about security.  Another example might be an algorithm that runs non-deterministically when it had previously been sold to the customer as a deterministic algorithm.

Comment: One of the most frustrating things I hear, when reporting a (genuine) bug is, "Oh, no-one has complained about that before". Arghh! Maybe I take bug-hunting and software quality too seriously to be a "serious" developer?

Comment: @AlainD Taking it seriously is fine.  It just takes coaching to phrase it =)  The reality is, unless you are working on open source in your free time, the business needs are at the forefront.  You just have to find the right way in your business to fix these serious issues, and then you're set.

Comment: As for "no-one has complained about that before," there are applications where that is a valid reason to avoid calling it a bug, in the name of keeping things running smoothly.  On the other hand, if you are working on numeric analysis software, and this bug could have made a customer's results subtly wrong, then it almost certainly needs to be logged as a bug because a customer may need to take back some analysis they presented to their customers.

Comment: I worked in an environment for a while where you never "refactored" anything.  You could do the changes, but you couldn't call it 'refactoring" because management had recently dealt with a multi-year "refactoring" project that they regretted.  Anything with that word brought back sore memories for them.  They understood full well when we talked around the term... we just couldn't use the term itself.

Comment: That part about "refactoring" being a dirty word describes my situation well. The codebase is a mix of modern C++ (parts badly, parts well-written) and 20+ year old C code that is largely unintelligible. Code comments are  scant or often wrong. The guy who wrote the core code left a few years ago and they've been through a string of developers since (something I was not aware of before starting). Trying to change the core is really tricky...but essential, in view. Management, though, are focused on the (urgent) business needs. It's catch-22.

Comment: @AlainD Sounds like every software package I've worked on in my career =D.  The one thing I have learned through fighting software like that is that it *cannot* be a fight.  You will always lose against those who are trying to secure your next paycheck.  I find the thing that discriminates the junior developers from the senior developers is not so much coding skill as their ability to reach out into the business world and sell the opportunities they need to fix things so that management feels it was their own idea.

Answer (score 1):

Bugs are prioritized differently, given different resources, planned differently, tracked differently, reported to customers differently, and closed differently than enhancements. Completely aside from the pride issues others have mentioned, when you mischaracterize a work item, there is a whole process ripple effect you set in motion. This is especially vexing to someone whose job is to manage that process.

If the ticket started and ended with you, it wouldn't matter so much. It's just a task you're working on. On my personal projects, I usually just create a GitHub issue to remember work to do and don't care about labeling it a bug or not. When other people are involved, it's courteous to be more precise.

Comment: Absolutely: The process has costs, which differ on how you name things and thus handle them.  (Esp. with regard to QA.) And in some organizations, part of the process is computing metrics on which the organization, some part of it, or some specific people in it (frequently managers) are measured.  For these reasons and others it can sometimes be the case that the difference between a bug and a feature or a bug and tech debt or a bug and whatever becomes a political issue instead of a technical "definition" issue.